# Reactjs test sinon spy mocked function returns a function and not a boolean

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, sinon

I'm trying to check that that `formIsValid` method in my `InformationGatheringFormContainer` component is calling one of the components props (`isInfoFormValid`) when executing:

```
export class InformationGatheringFormContainer extends React.Component{
...
formIsValid() {
    this.props.isInfoFormValid(this.state.invalid);
}
```

To do that, I'm using the sinon spy function:

```
it('formIsValid changes the state', () => {
    const mockFunction = sinon.spy();

    const baseProps = {
        isInfoFormValid: mockFunction,
    }

    const wrapper = shallow(<InformationGatheringFormContainer {...baseProps} />);
    wrapper.instance().formIsValid();
    expect(mockFunction).to.have.been.calledOnce.equal(true);

})
```

I would expect it to work, however this test gives:

```
AssertionError: expect(received).to.equal(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  true
Received:
  [Function proxy]

Difference:

  Comparing two different types of values. Expected boolean but received function.
```

So the function call is indeed detected but the `.to.have.been.calledOnce` enzyme method does not return a boolean here apparently.

I'm new to Reactjs Unit tests, and I'm a bit lost. How can the return of the `.to.have.been.calledOnce` have a different type than boolean ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found another way to do it:

```
expect(mockFunction.callCount).toEqual(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `calledOnce` [is a sinon spy property](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/#using-a-spy-to-wrap-an-existing-method), not [jest's expect](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect).
So, something like:

```
expect(mockFunction.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
```

should work (if you prefer `sinon`).

Worth to note that [jest has his own mocking mechanism](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api):

```
it('formIsValid changes the state', () => {
    const isInfoFormValid = jest.fn();

    const baseProps = {
        isInfoFormValid,
    }

    const wrapper = shallow(<InformationGatheringFormContainer {...baseProps} />);
    wrapper.instance().formIsValid();
    expect(isInfoFormValid).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

})
```